# Is there a resource which describes all of the log4net loggers used by NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, logging, log4net

I would like to heavily customize my NHibernate logging for performance diagnosis reasons. Is there a resource of all of the available loggers? Even better would be a resource describing what each logger logs at the various log levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion would be to examine the [source for nhibernate](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/) itself; the folder / namespace hierarchy should give you a rough idea of the available loggers.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to setting a logger for "NHibernate" and log all messages for a few sessions. I did this and was able to see a lot of hierarchal loggers (especially configuration and connection), but the stuff under "NHibernate.SQL" was notably missing. I suppose there is a weird log4net hierarchy configuration somewhere in there.